# Can a textile fiber cause an electrical short?

Tags: usb, short-circuit, conductivity

Let's say you are cleaning some USB ports/plugs with [chenille pipe cleaners](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1920&bih=942&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=chenille%20pipe%20cleaner) moistened with alcohol.  As you can see from the image of a USB port below, the raised wire contacts inside the port could cause chenille fibers to become stuck to them (and indeed that happened to me recently).

[image]

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chenille_fabric), chenille can be made from cotton, acrylic, rayon or olefin.  A couple of resources I found said that those materials are all electrically conductive to some degree:

- cotton is "slightly conductive"[<sup>1</sup>](https://www.trifield.com/content/tribo-electric-series/)
- acrylic has "fair to good" electrical conductivity[<sup>2</sup>](http://infohouse.p2ric.org/ref/12/11471.pdf)
- rayon has "fair" electrical conductivity[<sup>2</sup>](http://infohouse.p2ric.org/ref/12/11471.pdf)
- olefin has "excellent" electrical conductivity[<sup>2</sup>](http://infohouse.p2ric.org/ref/12/11471.pdf)

So if a chenille fiber got stuck inside a USB port, could that cause any problems with the operation of the port (such as by creating an electrical short if the fiber touched 2 of the wire contacts)?

Comment: Do you have any actual problem with the port, or just asking theoretically? If you have a problem, please describe it. Is it not working at all, or the connection is intermittent, or unreliable?

Comment: @AliChen I am asking theoretically, as I have not used any of the ports since cleaning them.

Comment: 1. The wire in the pipe cleaner could damage the contacts.  2.  A piece of fuzz would be more likely to prevent a good connection between contacts that are supposed to connect than to cause a short.

Comment: The one actual somewhat Scientific source you link clearly identifies these resources talk about TriboElectric properties. They have nothing to do with the actual conduction of low potential currents. Else we'd all be in a lot of trouble with our PVC, Polyolefin and ABS wrappings to plugs, plug sockets and cables.

Comment: Step one in being serious in engineering is to never look at material properties in a book that talks about safe ironing temperatures. That's my new motto now.

Comment: There are no visible conduction problems in the photo from creapage, leakage or dielectric no would I expect any from your description.

Comment: None of those fibers are conductive enough to cause any problem.  Do not be concerned. Damp cotton may be somewhat conductive, I am not sure. But acrylic, rayon and olefin are actually insulators, not conductors, and are hydrophobic, so not likely to be damp in the same way as cotton can be.

Comment: Basically, if those fibers could cause USB to stop working, USB would be totally unreliable, because the fibers are everywhere.

Comment: @mkeith So you don't think those fibers would prevent a good connection from being made, as mentioned in the one answer so far?

Comment: I have not seen any problems. I carry USB devices in backpacks and in my pocket and all kinds of places where there are lots of fibers around. I have not had any problems. The fibers are ubiquitous. If they caused problems, people would constantly be having problems.

Answer (score 2):

While some polymers can be somewhat conductive (that's how some organic devices work), those fibers you mentioned cannot be considered conductive: sweat, for instance, is orders of magnitude more conductive.

Instead, the problem is that those fibers are actually insulators, and therefore they will prevent a good contact between the two connectors. The contact surface will decrease and thus the contact resistance will increase. If such contacts are supposed to carry a large current (i.e. the power contacts), such increased resistance might induce eccessive voltage drop or even local overheating.